# Embedding Lua to C++ and wxWidgets using Eclipse IDE

Tags: c++, eclipse, lua

I am new to Lua so I am sorry if this is rather an easy question but it is driving me nuts. In my previous thread [A simple query on calling Lua 5.2 from C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643425/a-simple-query-on-calling-lua-5-2-from-c) I have used an easy C++ code to embed Lua in it. Things worked well but when I transfer that concept to a more complex project, the same code does not work. I have checked many sources but could not find a solution.

Here is my code:

```
#include "External/include/lua.hpp"

lua_State *luastate =NULL;

IMPLEMENT_APP(ScienceSuitApp);

bool ScienceSuitApp::OnInit()
{

    luastate=luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(luastate);
        ScienceSuitFrame* frame = new ScienceSuitFrame(0L);
       frame->Show();

      return true;
 }
```

Now when I try to compile the code, I am getting invalid arguments error for the luaL_openlibs(luastate) line. The error that the compiler gives:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void luaL_openlibs(*)
'       ScienceSuitApp.cpp      /ScienceLab     line 33     Semantic Error
```

This is actually happening whenever I call a Lua function such as luaL_dostring etc.. which takes lua_State as parameter. By the way, I am using Eclipse as IDE and wxWidgets as GUI if that should give a clue. Any my configuration for this set up is:
[image]

I "think" I have solved the problem. It stems from the fact that Eclipse throws a "semantic error" and not a "syntax error". Therefore, I followed the advice from [Eclipse CDT shows semantic errors, but compilation is ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148235/eclipse-cdt-shows-semantic-errors-but-compilation-is-ok). But now my question is what does it have to do with Indexing in Eclipse IDT? It feels like I am using Eclipse without knowing any of its internals.

Comment: Check if `luastate` is not NULL after `luastate=luaL_newstate();`

Comment: But the error is happening during compile time, not during run time.

Comment: Can you show the full error message for first error (make sure it is first error), and mark the source code in your post indicating the line referenced in message?

Comment: Are you including the Lua headers?

Comment: I am including the headers and also the library by the way shown at the image.